# Как получить доступ к Live Share через код

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Хочу получить доступ к Live Share через код для того чтобы получать ссылку и делать хост.
Но не могу найти Api.

Comment: Насколько я понял, это проприетарный продукт от Microsoft, исходники клиентских расширений не раскрываются, а протокол публично не документирован. Так что только через реверс-инжиниринг остается.